# Why a certain graph will not show?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I used ezplot to draw the graph for `$x^2-y^3=0$` and it turns out properly, however, if I square the equation and attempt to plot `$(x^2-y^3)^2=0$`, I get no graph at all. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the emergence of complex solutions.

For instance, with `ezplot` there is also a difference between `(x^2-y^3)=0.01` and `(x^2-y^3)^2=0.0001`, though they are quite close mathematically. When the right term decreases towards 0, the curve with the `^2` vanishes.

However, there is no difference between `x^2-y^3=0.01` and `x^2-y^3=(0.0001)^(1/2)` or `x^2-y^3=sqrt(0.0001)`.

So, I would suggest to plot something like `x^2-y^3=0^(1/2)`.

Weird enough !